# Why does #define INVALID_VALUE -999; give a syntax error when used?

Tags: c

I am trying to compare to a defined constants in C, and I have simplified my program to the following:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#define INVALID_VALUE -999;

int main(void)
{
    int test=0;
    if(test==INVALID_VALUE) //The error line..
        return INVALID_VALUE;
    return 0;
}
```

And when I use gcc to compile, it gives out error "**`error: expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token`**".

Is there any reason that this cannot be done?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove the semicolon from your INVALID_VALUE definition.

Macros are replaced lexically (character-by-character) with no understanding of the syntax around them.  Your macro INVALID_VALUE is set to `-999;`, so your if line expands the macro to:

```
if (test==-999;)
```

which is invalid C syntax.

Answer (score 6):

You need to remove the `;` in `#define INVALID_VALUE -999;`. See [the fixed code](http://ideone.com/pnWam).

You could have worked towards this conclusion by understanding what the error message `expected ‘)’ before ‘;’ token` was telling you. It's telling you that it expected to find a `)` before the `;` token, but from inspecting the line alone you don't see a `;`. So maybe there's one in the definition of `INVALID_VALUE`? Look up at `#define INVALID_VALUE -999;` and there it is! Think it should be there, but not sure? So let's try remove it and see if it works. Success!

[This page](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/PRE11-C.+Do+not+conclude+macro+definitions+with+a+semicolon) goes and explains why you shouldn't conclude a `#define` with a semicolon, even if it is needed in the use of the macro. It's good to learn as much as possible from your mistake so that you don't make it again. Quote:

> Macro definitions, regardless of
>   whether they expand to a single or
>   multiple statements should not
>   conclude with a semicolon. If
>   required, the semicolon should be
>   included following the macro
>   expansion. Inadvertently inserting a
>   semicolon at the end of the macro
>   definition can unexpectedly change the
>   control flow of the program.
>
> Another way to avoid this problem is
>   to prefer inline or static functions
>   over function-like macros.
>
> In general, the programmer should
>   ensure that there is no semicolon at
>   the end of a macro definition. The
>   responsibility for having a semicolon
>   where needed during the use of such a
>   macro should be delegated to the
>   person invoking the macro.

Answer (score 3):

#### The C Preprocessor Macro Language is Distinct from C

---

The ***;*** in the macro definition should be removed.

This is an understandable mistake. If C were designed today, the macro language might be more integrated with the rest of C.

But on 16-bit machines in the early 1970's when C was invented, it was unwise to write an overly complicated program. It would end up useless as there would be no memory remaining to actually *run* the big masterpiece program, and even simple programs ran slowly.

So C was split into a rather simple macro preprocessor that was, originally, a completely separate program, and the compiler proper.  The preprocessor program made no attempt to parse C beyond understanding the lexical analysis model.

When 32-bit machines took over, the preprocessor was typically integrated into the parser, but naturally the language needed to remain the same.

Answer (score 2):

The semi colon at the end of

```
#define INVALID_VALUE -999;
```

Classic.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a semicolon after defining something. #define is actually a macro, and it will do an inline expansion on compile.

Thus,

```
#define IDENTIFIER 10;
int j = IDENTIFIER;
```

will expand as:

```
int j = 10;;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change macro

from:

```
#define INVALID_VALUE -999;
```

to

```
#define INVALID_VALUE -999
```

Bye